# Third time's the Charm: any research into how we learn from error?

Tags: learning, sleep

I have often told people that I make a mistake two different ways before I really understand a situation. Is there any research that explains how and why this works? As an analogy, there is something called a "paperclip tree", a branching structure of linked paperclips (or any other small objects that can be connected loosely). You can find the longest path through the tree by picking it up anywhere, then grasping the lowest point and picking it up again. Absolute, guaranteed, must work every time.

So, is learning by making two mistakes something like this? Something like triangulation - two points of view? I also find that I have to sleep twice before something is really integrated in to my awareness and memory. After just one sleep it disappears and can't be recalled. This is why I often tell people that I cannot remember yesterday, but before that is clear. Also why naps are so helpful for learning. Any thoughts in how these things all work? Back propagation? Default Processing? Thank you.